# How to draw the contour inside the contour opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have the following image and I want to draw the contour inside the red contour (line). So another colour contour will be attached to the red one from inside. [image]

Comment: Draw a white filled contour on a black background the size of your image. Then erode the contour a little using morphology. Then compute a new contour from the eroded image. Draw this new contour on your original image and it will be inside the existing contour.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
red contour is Yours and green contour is the contour inside.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('input.png')
gray = cv2.imread('input.png',0)
img=np.uint8(img)

blank=np.zeros([768,1024,3],np.uint8)
cnts = cv2.findContours(255-gray, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(blank, [c], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
erosion_image = cv2.erode(blank, kernel, iterations=2)

blank = np.uint8(erosion_image[:,:,0])
cnts = cv2.findContours(blank, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

cv2.imwrite('output.png', img)
```